# How to read temperature with Intel Extreme Tuning Utility?

Tags: cpu, performance, temperature

I recently downloaded [Intel Extreme Tuning Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-) and I've been unable to find where the CPU temperature is displayed. I've even found where to select whether temps are displayed in Fahrenheit or Celsius, but not the display itself.

Comment: Did it put something in the system tray?

Comment: It did, and I can open the GUI from there or from the desktop icon.  I just can't find any option on the GUI for displaying temperature.

Comment: Download and read the release notes for that utility, might be some clues in there...https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 settings for the lower right and left panes, use the wrench icons to set what temps you want to see in the lower pane. Package temp is the overall temp of the processor, you can add core temps also. That being said it depends on what processor you have what settings are available.

[image]

.
These are the left pane settings

[image]
[image]

.

These are the right pane settings

[image]
[image]

Comment: For some reason my "Settings for system graphs" and "Configure System Monitors" windows only show 5 different options to be displayed, (CPU utilization, memory utilization, processor graphics frequency, graphics voltage and memory frequency) and none of them are temperature related.  I thought it could be my hardware, so I installed Intel Extreme on a different computer as well, but ran into the exact same scenario.  Did you download the program from [the Intel site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-)?

Comment: Depends on the processor what can be displayed, some processors don't have the required temp sensors built in. What is your processor?

Comment: The first computer has an i7 2600, the other computer has an i5 2410m.

Comment: My screenshots are for a i7-4790, I can only guess why you don't see what I see for my processor.

Comment: Yep, I looked at the release notes and I think my processors are earlier generations than what the tool is intended for.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Mine is a gen 4, I guess yours is earlier than that.

Comment: They are both 2nd generation.